# JSON from Javascript not decoding in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, json, post

I've been going bananas trying to get some data from Javascript on one page to post to a php file asynchronously. I'm not even attempting to do anything with the data, just a var_dump to spit back out from the ajax call. NULL over and over again.

I've checked the JSON with JSONLint and it validates just fine. I'm getting my JSON from JSON.stringify - Firebug tells me I'm getting the following:

```
{"items":[["sa1074","1060"],["sa1075","1061"]]}
```

I've tried php://input, as well as json_decode_nice from the PHP manual comments about the function, and I've tried using utf8_encode - is there something wrong with my JSON?

EDIT: Derpity dee probably should have planned this post a bit more haha. Here's my PHP (using a suggestion from PHP manual comments)

```
function json_decode_nice($json, $assoc = FALSE){
$json = str_replace(array("\n","\r"),"",$json);
$json = preg_replace('/([{,])(\s*)([^"]+?)\s*:/','$1"$3":',$json);
return json_decode($json,$assoc);
}
if (isset($_POST['build'])){
    $kit = file_get_contents('php://input');
    var_dump(json_decode_nice($kit));
}
```

And the JS used to create it:

```
        var jsonKit = JSON.stringify(kit);
    $.post("kits.php?", {"build" : jsonKit},
        function(data) {
            $("#kitItems").html(data);
        });
```

Also: Our host is on PHP 5.2 - I found this out when I uploaded a perfectly good redbean class only to have it explode. Had to re-implement with legacy redbean. Our host is busted.

SOLVED: Thanks to all who commented. Didn't think to check $_POST to see what was coming in. Quotes were being escaped with slashes in the $_POST and json_decode was choking on it. Adding this line before decoding solved the problem. Also forgot to set true to return an associative array. Thanks!

```
$kit = str_replace('\\', '', $kit);
```

Comment: Please show more code, especially how you make the call. If `var_dump($_POST)` results in NULL, your problem is earlier up the chain

Comment: Please post your JS and your PHP. :)

Comment: Don't forget to make friends with `json_last_error()`, although this sounds like the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I hadn't thought to dump ($_POST) - I'm just so used to posting stuff and not worrying about it. I guess you have to go back to basics. Found out that stuff was being escaped with slashes when I dumped ($_POST). Thanks!

Comment: And magic quotes screw up yet another PHP program... http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

Comment: don't use `str_replace` to drop the slashes; turn off magic-quotes. It's a legacy of old PHP versions. If you *must* keep it switched on, then `stripslashes()` is the correct function to use. But yes, if your host still has magic quotes enabled then you're right: your web host sucks. Find another one.

Comment: Strangely enough, stripslashes caused a NULL return too - that's the only reason i used str_replace. Seemed a bit hacky to me too but I suppose it'll have to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing code - I'm just guessing here ... are you using a `true` `assoc` variable in your [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)?

```
<?php json_decode($jsonString, true); ?>
```

That had me stumped on a decode for quite some time my first time trying to decode something,